# Way to clean up child process address space even its still alive

Tags: memory, process, virtual, parent

In my process i have created 10 threads and will use those threads till my application is alive. Each thread will perform some file input and output operation every time. So the problem is every time thread start executing then my process virtual memory is getting increased. 
My analysis is that when one file input output task is allowcated to the thread then the file will be loaded to thread address space when thread start to copy the file and after copy is completed then the thread address space will not be cleared as still the thread is not exited. So if i once again assign another task to the thread then the new file will be loaded to the thread address space.

Hence the main process virtual memory address space will be increase. SO Please correct me if i am wrong and also help to know this has some problem if the process run for log time.

Comment: When you lanch an application from [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) the app is instrumented to track individual memory allocations along with the associated call stack. You may see how virtual memory address space will be increased.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here.

1) Threads do not have their own memory address space. Processes do. (However, threads do get their own thread local storage.)

2) In managed languages, objects are not cleaned up and the heap compacted until the garbage collector is run. The garbage collector is not run until it needs to (e.g. the program is close to running out of memory). As long as the object has no strong references to it (nothing running can reach it) then the object will get cleaned up when the program needs it to be cleaned up, and you don't need to do anything else. If you want the garbage collector to run early, however, tell it to.

By the way, if resources are needed commonly amongst many different threads, you could consider having some sort of global cache for them. However, early optimization is a grievous sin, so don't go to all that effort until you've determined it solves a REAL problem.

Comment: then what is cause of virtual memory increase? and the process is written in c++